# How do I connect to a remote mysql server using DBI?

Tags: mysql, ruby, dbi

I am having trouble connecting to a MySQL DB on a remote server via Ruby and the DBI gem.

For this example, the DB host's address is 000.00.00.000, and the name of the DB is `testdb`.

Should `username` be my personal username I SSH into the server with or a specific MySQL username?
Should `password` be my personal password I SSH with or the MySQL password I use once I'm on?
Do I need to specify the port or anything else along with the IP address?

Here is the code I'm currently trying to use, which I found [on this tutorial](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/ruby-mysql.html)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
require 'dbi'

#connect to mysql database

begin
 # connect to the MySQL server
 dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:testdb:000.00.00.000", 
                    "username", "password")
 # get server version string and display it
 row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
 puts "Server version: " + row[0]
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
 puts "An error occurred"
 puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
 puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
ensure
 # disconnect from server
 dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

When I run:

```
Error code:    2003
Error message: Can't connect to MySQL server on  ... (60)
```

On SSH I am currently getting into MySQL with this command:

```
mysql -u root testdb -p
```

I have the password for this and that functions in my terminal.

What should I be putting in the DBI connect statement to connect correctly via Ruby?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) gem. It's much easier to work with than DBI, and allows you to work using datasets or models as a true ORM. It's also going to free you from having to write SQL for the most part, allowing you to easily and quickly port your code to other DBMs. The [README](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) is a great starting place to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you run MySQL server on your local machine, try changing your connect line to:

```
dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:testdb:127.0.0.1",
     "root", "<rootmysqlpassword>")
```

Comment: It's a remote server, and replacing 127.0.0.1 with the remote ip is not doing the trick for me. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Are you sure firewall is not blocking you? Can you `telnet server 3306` and have it not immediately give you an error?